# Reduce order in Bison

Tags: bison

I am writing a compiler using Bison and I am trying to use the same function with while and repeat loops. I need the parser to reduce "`condition`" before  "`statements_off`".   ¿Can I specify the reduction order?

Here is the code for the loops:

```
loop_stmt:
        WHILE line condition DO ENDL line statements_off DONE
            { $$ = process_while($<elem>3, $<elem>7, $<ival>2, $<ival>6); }
    |   REPEAT ENDL line statements_off UNTIL line condition    
            { $$ = process_not($<elem>7);
              $$ = process_while($$, $<elem>4, $<ival>6, $<ival>3);  }
    |   FOR for_condition DO ENDL statements_off DONE
            { $$ = process_for($<elem>5, $<ival>2); }
    ;

condition: '(' expr_bool_or ')' { validate_bool_condition($<elem>2); $$ = $<elem>2; }
    ;
```

Comment: By the time any of the action code shown here is executed, all the elements in the grammar have been reduced (both `condition` and `statements_off`).  However, in the REPEAT code, the `statements_off` will almost inevitably be reduced before the `condition`, whereas in the WHILE code the reverse will be true.  It isn't clear to me that there's any way to alter that usefully; I think you should be reviewing why you need the condition reduced before the statements, and removing that restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bison reductions are evaluated bottom-up and left-to-right. That is an essential part of the algorithm.

That gives you a tiny bit of latitude -- occassionally you can write a grammar so that bottom-up reductions will have a right-to-left effect -- but you really shouldn't. Semantic analysis works best when you parse into an AST (ideally independent of the order of action evaluation) and then walk the AST as necessary and convenient.

Writing a one-pass compiler by directly linearizing the language into three-address code may seem like a simplification, or an optimisation. But it will end up feeling more like a straight-jacket because of the difficulty of warping a process designed to produce a tree into a linear control flow.

One-pass compilers -- the Lua compiler springs to mind -- often end up having to reorder chunks of generated code, both because of constructs such as this question and in order to implement non-peephole optimizations.

(It's actually pretty common to shuffle the pre-test in `while` and `for` statements to the end of the loop, which seems to be the opposite of what is being contemplated here.)

---

To be clear about the possibilities, consider the difference between:

```
expressions: 
           | expressions expression     { printf("%d\n", $2); }
```

and

```
expressions:
           | expression expressions     { printf("%d\n", $1); }
```

Both of these reduce `expression` left-to-right, but the bottom-up reduction of `expressions` causes the second excerpt to print the values of the expressions in reverse order. If `expression` were not recursive (which it almost certainly is), you could unfactor it into the `expressions` production, causing the reductions of the expressions themselves to correspond to the bottom-up logic. But this transformation is extremely limited, because it will only work until you hit a recursive production, and almost all interesting productions are recursive. (`statement` and `expression` being just two examples.)